# Qual è il significato di "resa" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, nouns

Sto leggendo *L'affaire Moro* di Leonardo Sciascia. Ecco un brano di questo libro:

> E si può oggi dire – retrospettivamente e statisticamente – che il margine di rischio era minimo e solo casualmente poteva insorgere; o addirittura inesistente, considerando la nessuna **resa** delle azioni che la polizia condusse. Ma, al momento, quelle azioni erano tanto conclamate dalla stampa e dalla radiotelevisione, così decise, decisive e numerose apparivano, che si poteva anche nutrire l’illusione, e dalla parte delle Brigate rosse il timore, dovessero sortire un qualche effetto.

Ho difficoltà a capire il senso di "resa" in questo passaggio. Ho cercato questo termine nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/resa/), ma non riesco a vedere a quale accezione corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel testo. Il significato della frase è forse che le azioni della polizia non condussero a nessun risultato utile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cit. Vocabolario Treccani: "3. L’utile economico, la prestazione o il servizio, che una cosa dà o fornisce"

La frase in questo caso vuol significare che le azioni condotte dalla polizia non sortirono alcun effetto o in altri termini che furono di nessuna efficacia.

Comment: Sono d'accordo sul senso generale della spiegazione, ma sei sicuro che intendevi davvero dire “[perpetrare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/perpetrare/)” («Commettere intenzionalmente, mandare a effetto azioni disoneste, malvagie o illecite»)?

Comment: No "perpetrare" non è il termine corretto, intendevo "condurre".

Answer (score 2):

Il significato penso sia quello che le azioni della Polizia non hanno portato a nessun risultato, nessun esito di rilievo.

Il passaggio potrebbe essere riscritto come:

> ...considerando gli scarsi risultati delle azioni che la Polizia condusse...

Inoltre, su Treccani, leggendo la voce [resa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/resa/) il significato in questione sarebbe quello indicato dalla accezione 3: resa dal punto di vista economico, quantitativa, che in senso un po' figurato si applica nel nostro caso ad un'azione concreta.

Answer (score -1):

Certo Resa proviene da Risultato riferendosi al fatto che nessuna delle operazioni della polizia aveva portato a qualcosa di concreto.
Forse vuole anche alludere a resa nel senso di Arrendersi, come allora in uso  "Nessuna resa al terrorismo" ma il senso è chiaramente il primo.

Comment: “Resa proviene da Risultato”: puoi chiarire meglio? In che senso “proviene da”?

Answer (score -1):

"La nessuna resa" può essere sostituito da "il risultato nullo".

Oppure si può tradurre (in forma a mio parere più elegante) con "considerando che le azioni della polizia non hanno prodotto alcun risultato".

Comment: Proviene nel senso che resa è sininimo di risultato. "Resa" è una parola il cui significato dipende dal contesto in cui la parola è usata.